# React, state setter not updating the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

`useState()` can't set file object. I added comments in the code to explain what's happening:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState<File>()
const onChange = async (
    imageList: ImageListType,
    addUpdateIndex: number[] | undefined
) => {
    if (imageList[0].file) {
        console.log("first image: ", imageList[0].file) // this line print out the right file object, but setFile NOT working below line
        setFile(imageList[0].file)
    }

    console.log("file: ", file) // this line will print undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setFile(imageList[0].file)`, a re-render is need to have `file` updated. Updating a state is an asynchronous task, this why you are getting `undefined`. To see the updated value of `file`, you could add the `console.log` just after calling `useState`, this way:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState<File>()
console.log(file); // you will get undefined first, and after calling onChange the updated value
```

Or, you could use an `useEffect`, like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 if (file){
   console.log(file)
 }
},[file])
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that useState can set any type of object
however the problem here that you are setting the file then logging it which 90% work why is that?
that's because **ReactJs useState sets its state asynchronously**

so in order to verify the file object add this to your code

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(file)
},[file])
```